# Arduino Pi-3 Ubuntu MATE not compiling

Tags: arduino-ide, raspberrypi, ubuntu

When I try to upload a script to my Genuino Uno from the Linux ARM distro on genuino.cc/downloads it spits out this during compiling.

`avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM0": Permission denied
ioctl("TIOCMGET"): Inappropriate ioctl for device`

Has anyone got any ideas?

Thanks,
Caleb

Comment: Have you performed the correct permissions manipulating commands as detailed in the Linux install instructions for the Arduino IDE?

Comment: No I didn't, but after doing so the Arduino IDE works! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following the advice left by Majenko, I went to https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Linux and followed the instuctions at the bottom of the page:

If you get an error Error opening serial port ... you need to set serial port permission.

Open Terminal and type:

`ls -l /dev/ttyACM*`

you will get something like:

`crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 5 apr 23.01 ttyACM0`

The "0" at the end of ACM might be a different number, or multiple entries might be returned. The data we need is "dialout" (is the group owner of the file).

Now we just need to add our user to the group:

`sudo usermod -a -G dialout <username>`

where  is your linux user name. You will need to log out and log in again for this change to take effect.